# Get Image URL to Listbox Binding from JSON

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I have my JSON request that grabs the URI and can even put the items in binding but NOT the images.

XAML:

```
 <Image delay:LowProfileImageLoader.UriSource="{Binding ImageUrl}" Width="120" Height="120" />
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" FontSize="30" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
```

Now once I get the Feed I run it as so:

```
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(e.Result)))
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ProviderChannels.RootObject));
            var providerResult = (ProviderChannels.RootObject)dataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);


            if (providerResult.ServiceDetailsResult != null)
            {

                ProviderChannels.ItemsSource = providerResult.ServiceResult.Lineup.Channels;

            }
```

The issue is, I can't get the images to take in the ImageUrl that is from:

```
    public class Channeli
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public List<object> ChannelImages { get; set; }

    }
```

The feed/ChannelImages does this:

```
    "ChannelImages": [
                    {
                        "ImageUrl": "http://the-url-generated.com/file.png",
                        "ImageUseType": null,
                    }
```

The ChannelImages reports a ImageUrl and a bunch of other data but I need strictly the ImageUrl but seems even in the XAML if I put ImageUrl it won't work but how do I use the ChannelImages to get ImageUrl?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The images are stored wherever the JSON feed links them from (e.g. the ImageUri could have an image URL that goes to a Google Image).

Answer (score 0):

You should forward string as a ImageURL, not a list of object like you are doing now.

For everything to work fine with this code you have now, your *Channels* class should look something like this:

```
 public class Channels
 {
     public string DisplayName { get; set; }
     public string ImageUrl { get; set; } 
 }
```

Comment: The only problem is the feed looks like this (or look above, I formatted it for easier reading):

"ChannelImages": [
                        {
                            "ImageUrl": "http://image-url-generated.com/imagename.png",
                            "ImageUseType": null,

Comment: I actually did generate the class from that site (as I do with all of my JSON Feeds). Unfortunately still doesn't capture the ImageUrl.